# Material UI > Backdrop > only for some subcomponent of the page

Tags: material-ui

Is there any way how to enhance a backdrop from example in https://material-ui.com/components/backdrop/ to show loading circle only above the single component (in case some page has more component), not above the whole page?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: What about <Skeleton>? https://material-ui.com/components/skeleton/

Answer (score 18):

`Backdrop` are `fixed` positioned by default, that's why it covers the whole page.

To achieve the result you want, we have to change its `position` to `absolute` and contain it inside an element with `relative` position —  this element can be your component. If you're new in CSS positions check this [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) from developer.mozilla.org.

Knowing all that, we can come up with the following codes

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  parent: {
    position: "relative",
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    zIndex: 0,
  },
  backdrop: {
    position: "absolute"
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.parent}>
      <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={true}>
        <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
      </Backdrop>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also we have to define [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) on either parent or backdrop element to make it work. Not sure why though.

I created a codesandbox for you to play with.

[image: Edit lively-wind-47fk4]

Answer (score 3):

i have created a custom componenet that i use if i want to block only part of the UI:

```js
"use strict";

/** external libraries */
import React from "react";
import Backdrop from "@mui/material/Backdrop";
import CircularProgress from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";

const BlockUi = ({open, onClose, children}) => {
    return (
        <div style={{"position": "relative"}}>
            <Backdrop
                sx={{color: "#FFFFFF", zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1, "position": "absolute"}}
                open={open}
                onClick={() => onClose()}
            >
                <CircularProgress color="inherit"/>
            </Backdrop>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}

export default BlockUi;
```

and i use it like this:

```js
"use strict";

/** external libraries */
import React from "react";
import BlockUi from "./BlockUi";

const JsonForm = ({fields, onSubmit}) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)

    const stopLoading = () => {
        setLoading(false)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <BlockUi open={loading} onClose={stopLoading}>
                <button type="submit" onClick={() => {
                    console.log(loading)
                    setLoading(true)
                }}>Submit
                </button>
            </BlockUi>
        </div>
    );
}

export default JsonForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Backdrop** component of Material UI is set to `position: 'fixed'` by default, that's why it covers the whole page.

If you want it to reside and position itself like any other component typically on the DOM, all you have to do is to reset its position back to `relative`, for instance:

```js
<Backdrop open={true} sx={{ position: 'relative' }}>
   <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
</Backdrop>
```

and you don't need to change the parent component since it *should* be in your case see to **relative** by default if you're not changing it. But if you have crazy positions going in your app here and there, then you might consider changing that as well.